# How to connect two d3 js svg circles with a line or path?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

hope someone can help me. 
So I create 2 or more draggable circles and then I want to connect them with a line or path. How can I do that? And how can I make the line/path follow the circle when I drag it around? 
Here is the code for the circle creation:

```
svg.append("circle")
    .data([{ x: 250, y: 250, r: 25 }])
    .attr('class', 'draggableCircle')
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr('r', function(d) { return d.r; })
    .attr("stroke-width", 0)
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("id", guid())
    .call(drag)
    .style('fill', getRandomColor());
```

Is it somehow possible to hook a line/path to two circles?

With kind regards